# how to serve local static files in development when hosted in S3

Tags: javascript, python, django, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

I'm storing my static files in S3 according to this tutorial:  https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/

I am developing a lot of javascript and want to serve my javascript files locally only when in my development environment. Otherwise I would have to keep uploading my js files every time I want to test.

My static files settings look like this currently:

```
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'my.custom_storage.StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
```

I created a local_settings.py file with setttings that point locally:

```
STATICFILES_LOCATION = '/local/myapp/common/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/local/myapp/common/static/"
```

No matter what I change here, my app looks for the js files at the S3 url:  http://s3.amazonaws.com...

**How can I have my app look locally for static files when in development so I can rapidly test my js files?**

Answer (score 0):

I set the following in my local_settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
```

Then it looks for all static assets at localhost.